# Get sub-string within non-standard pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get a sub-string in the cases below:

```
TruckScaleEntry_DriverId_1535
                ^------^

EntryCreateForm_TruckScaleEntry_DriverId_1535_SelectWidget_Code
                                ^------^
```

In the examples above I want the `DriverId`(It **isn't always** `DriverId`, it may change as well) but I never know which pattern I'm dealing with. Actually I got it to work with two regex and two methods(`match` and `replace`) together. But I want to know if there is a better - and simpler - way to achieve it.

What I got is:

```js
console.log("TruckScaleEntry_DriverId_1535".match(/(?:.*TruckScaleEntry_)[^_]*/)[0].replace(/^.*_/, ''));

console.log("EntryCreateForm_TruckScaleEntry_DriverId_1535_SelectWidget_Code".match(/(?:.*TruckScaleEntry_)[^_]*/)[0].replace(/^.*_/, ''));
```

Yeah it is ugly. Can I do something clearer with just one regex and one method?

Comment: do you want **[this](https://regex101.com/r/wF4fG5/1)**?

Comment: @rock321987 not exactly. I've updated the question because `DriverId` is an example, it may change as well.

Comment: so [this](https://regex101.com/r/wF4fG5/2)?

Comment: @rock321987 sure, it worked. I used with `match(/.../)[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regular expression with `replace`:

```js
var s = 'EntryCreateForm_TruckScaleEntry_DriverId_1535_SelectWidget_Code';

res = s.replace(/^.*?TruckScaleEntry_(.+?)_.*$/, '$1');
document.write(res + '<br>');

// Alternative

res = s.match(/TruckScaleEntry_(.+?)_/)[1];
document.write(res + '<br>');
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, did this solve your issue? Could you give some feedback?

Comment: Sure, I've used your solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Results of capturing groups are stored in `match objects`, which can be accessed by `match[1]` etc.

*JS Demo*

```js
var str = 'EntryCreateForm_TruckScaleEntry_DriverId_1535_SelectWidget_Code';
var regex = /TruckScaleEntry_([^_]+)/;
document.writeln(str.match(regex)[1]);
```